# How to use grep with $ anchor in the regex pattern?

Tags: regex, grep

I have searched the web ([here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux)) and searched in SO as well, but i didnt understand why grep fails to match lines end with the anchor `$`

#### my input file

```
f_Hndlr_foo=0xd0001244 0x4
f_Doj_cmdmem=0x7ffe8710 0x44
f_Doj_getHif=0xd0001248 0x4
f_tpl_geBufferPtr_rom=0x7ffe8754 0x6A
f_tDoj_cmdmem=0x7ffe8710 0x21
f_tDoj_getHif=0xd0001248 0x43
f_tpl_geBufferPtr_rom=0x7ffe8754 0x21A
```

I need to match the lines that end in `0x4` only! I have called `grep` with all the froms below and nothing match and extract the lines i need! what i am doing wrong?

```
grep -E "0x4$" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo.txt"
grep -E ".0x4$" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo.txt"
grep -E " 0x4$" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo.txt"
grep -E 0x4$ "C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo.txt"
```

I am runing on win7 comand line. the grep version is: **grep (GNU grep) 3.1**

Comment: Just tried on my Mac, `grep -E "0x4$" thefile` does give me back `f_Hndlr_foo=0xd0001244 0x4` and `f_Doj_getHif=0xd0001248 0x4`.

Comment: i can match the line in different way or with different anchors but i want to know what is wrong here with the $ anchor! thank you. maybe its something related to win7 OS?

Comment: Use dos2unix to get rid of DOS line endings, than it's gonna work

Comment: My application run on win7 hosts. so i cant assume that my hosts have this application. i need a cmd built in function like `grep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) expect an Unix like line ending, you need :

```
grep '0x4[[:cntrl:]]*$' Input_File
```

Or consider passing `dox2unix` tool on the file before to do it simpler.

Check: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176505/12574

Comment: I have tried you answer. no result. not working! did you try this on your computer and gives you a match?

Comment: Do you have access to the command `od -c file` ? If yes, can you share the output ?

Comment: Sure I have 2 matches

Comment: i have access. but i kill the command cos my terminal is full of gebresh

Comment: Just one line please, like: `grep "f_Hndlr_foo=0xd0001244" file | od -c`

Comment: this is the output (for other line as u see)




0000000   f   _   p   l   D   o   j   _   c   m   d   H   n   d   l   r
0000020   =   0   x   d   0   0   0   1   2   4   4       0   x   4  \r
0000040  \n
0000041

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216148/discussion-between-adam-and-gilles-quenot).

Comment: ` \r 0000040 \n` looks suspicious.

Comment: Can you pass `dos2unix` on a copy of the file, then give it a new try ?

Comment: I am not surprise at all that after converting the file to `unix` with `dos2unix` it worked perfectly! worked with `grep -E "0x4$" C:\....` without `*` before the `$`. 
windows!  :- (

Anyway, i can convert the file in real time to unix and process it cos dos2unix is shell built in in cmd win7.

Comment: so the conclusion is, this will not work with dos text files?! or can i overcome this without conversion to unix text file?

Comment: i can. lets move to the chat room i will send you a sample.